# How to get numbers in a certain range in a list?

Tags: c#, list

I have a list of integers

> 2,5,6,9,45,48,54,76,97,102,134,203,234,245,267,289,299

I want to get a list of numbers from 31 through 255. How to code it in C#?

Comment: That's one of the simplest programming question I can imagine. Have you already tried to write some code? It can be easily solved using `for` loop and `if` statement... You won't learn programming unless you try to program on your own.

Comment: As the list is sorted, you can use binary search to find the min and max element indices in log(n) time and then just iterate on that range. Please try yourself first.

Comment: @Prince Since, the list is sorted(ascending order), there is no need for binary search, obviously the last and the zeroth element will be max and min respectively.

Comment: @ps06756 I said element indices NOT elements; OP wants a range of elements (min = 31, max = 255). IMHO it makes perfect sense to do that. How else would you avail a sorted list?

Answer (score 3):

Hopefully this would work. Just tested it right now and it worked fine.

```
int[] x = {2,5,6,9,45,48,54,76,97,102,134,203,234,245,267,289,299};

List<int> y = new List<int>();

for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
{
    if ( (x[i] >= 31) && (x[i] <= 255) )
    {
         y.Add(x[i]);
    }
}
```

So I use an array for `x`. Then I make a List called `y`. I would use the loop to check if the values meet the condition. If they do I will add them in the `y` List.

```
foreach (int k in y)
{
    Console.WriteLine(k);
}
```

Use this loop just to make sure it works (optional).

Next time please show effort before you post a question. Also, this is a simple algorithm so it's all about the loops. Even a beginner programmer should know this as long as you know arrays and loops basics. Welcome to Stack Overflow.

**Ansible's Answer (more efficient)**

But because this is an ordered array we can make this a more efficient though, by stopping our search after we are past our upper bound. We know none of those numbers will be within our bound. We can do this by simply breaking from the for loop.

```
int[] x = {2,5,6,9,45,48,54,76,97,102,134,203,234,245,267,289,299};

List<int> y = new List<int>();

for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
{
    if ( (x[i] >= 31) && (x[i] <= 255) )
    {
         y.Add(x[i]);
    }
    else if (x[i] > 255)
    {
       // We are past the upper bound, we are okay to stop the for loop now.
       break;
    }
}
```

But beyond this we can make this still more efficient by implementing a binary search for the lower bound. What this does is instead of starting at the beginning of the array going through all the values, we can start in the middle. We can know by looking at value 97 (in the middle of the array) that our lower bound must be in the first half of the array. This already splits the amount of searching we are doing in half. We can keep doing this, cutting the array in half until we find the value we are looking for.

Putting it all together it would look something like this.

```
int[] x = {2,5,6,9,45,48,54,76,97,102,134,203,234,245,267,289,299};

List<int> y = new List<int>();

int lowerBoundIndex = binarySearch(array, 0, x.length, 31);

for (int i = lowerBoundIndex; i < x.Length; i++)
{
    if ( (x[i] >= 31) && (x[i] <= 255) )
    {
         y.Add(x[i]);
    }
    else if (x[i] > 255)
    {
       // We are past the upper bound, we are okay to stop the for loop now.
       break;
    }
}

public int binarySearch(int[] array, int lowerbound, int upperbound, int key) {
    int position;

    // To start, find the subscript of the middle position.
    position = (lowerbound + upperbound) / 2;

    while (!IsTargetIndex(array, position, key) && (lowerbound <= upperbound)) {
        if (array[position] > key) // If the number is > key, ..
        { // decrease position by one.
            upperbound = position - 1;
        } else {
            lowerbound = position + 1; // Else, increase position by one.
        }
        position = (lowerbound + upperbound) / 2;
    }


    if (lowerbound <= upperbound) {
        return position;
    } 

    return -1;
}

public boolean IsTargetIndex(int[] array, int position, int key)
{
    int current = array[position];
    int previous;
    if (position == 0)
        previous = -1;
    else
        previous = array[position -1];

    if ((previous < key) && (current >= key))
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

The binary search was taken from here, but I had to modify it because we are not looking for an exact match, but the first item that is larger or equal to the lower bound. This is done in IsTargetIndex.

This may or may not be overkill. If your array is small, then this may not be a big performance gain. But imagine if your array was millions of nodes, then this could be a huge time saver.

Next time please show effort before you post a question. Also, this can be done with a simple algorithm so it's all about the loops. Even a beginner programmer should know this as long as you know arrays and loops basics. Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: You could use a binary search to find the first element since they are sorted. Or at the very least you should add a break if x[i] > 255 so we don't search the rest of the numbers.

Comment: @ansible Oh I've heard of Binary Searching but I don't know the code on that. To be honest I'm not that much of a programming pro so yeah I'm trying to just stick with whatever a beginner could understand. I've been programming a lot but never became a pro level one.

Comment: No problem, suggested an edit to your answer to include these things. The basic idea of a binary search is not too complicated and it's a pretty neat idea.

Comment: Aww I went offline before I was able to approve it :( Oh well I'll edit it for you then. EDIT: Done added yours @ansible